# VCD dump for vhdl simulation via modelsim. HOWTO?

Tags: simulation, dump, vhdl, modelsim

It's the first time i try to generate a VCD and i am getting some troubles.

I have a testbench called bench_minimips.vhdl that contain the entity sim_minimips.
I want simulate it and get a VCD out of it.

i am typing the following command in the Modelsim shell:

```
vsim work.sim_minimips
vcd file myvcd1.vcd
vcd add -file bench_minimips.vhd/*
run
```

but if i open myvcd1.vcd in an empty file. What should i do to create the dump?

I tryed as well as sudgested in another forum the command:

```
wlf2vcd -o myvcd2.vcd vsim.wlf
```

but a error is generated.

I am really lost in understanding because all the websites i find tells you to use a TCL generated by altera or some other company and i do not have theyr content to look at.

Does someone knows what should i do?

Best,
Stefano

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-file` parameter to `vcd add` is not used to specify signals but the name of the VCD (if you've created several).

What you want to do instead is to add objects in your simulation. For example:

```
vcd file myvcd1.vcd
vcd add -r /sim_minimips/*
```